# Assembly code mixed in with my C++ code. How to port to 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am porting 32 bit C++ code into 64 bit in VS2008.  The old code has mixed code written in assembly.
Example:

```
__asm

{
  mov esi, pbSrc
  mov edi, pbDest

  ...

}
```

I have read somewhere that I need to remove all assembly code and put them all in a separate project and somehow link to it.  Can somebody give me the step x step procedure to do this.  I know C++ & C# but don't know assembly language.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use intrinsic functions to perform your tasks, or cannot write the equivalent in C/c++, you're going to have to dive into x64 assembly language.  From a high level:

1) Assuming that you're starting with x86 assembly language routines, you'll need to port them to x64.

2) Use [ML64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx) (Microsoft x64 assembler) or an equivalent assembler to assemble your routines into .OBJs that you can link into your C/C++ project.

3) Set up a custom build step that invokes the assembler on your .ASM files.

Good luck!

Comment: It's time to check out ML64.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ 2005, 2008, or 2010 don't support assembly inlining when compiling for 64-bit platforms. x64 ASM just has way too many intricacies and complexities that can screw up the C(++) code around the `__asm` block so they just don't allow it. In short, there's no way to "port" it.

I suggest using 64-bit intrinsics with `#define` and `#ifdef` when trying to cross-architecture compile such low-level code. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2k70f3s.aspx

**Edit**: If you really know what you're doing, however, you can save the proper ASM bytecodes in some sort of a buffer array and execute that "raw" - via a `void*` pointer and `VirtualProtect()` or something similar. Of course, you need to understand x64 calling/returning conventions since you'd essentially be calling a function. Note that this is 99.9% of the time a **bad** idea.